I20 hyundai not starting on occasions until the imobilizer light lights then its ok
Hyundai i20 2013.
Battery 6months old and tested good.
New key programed.
ECU replaced about a year ago.
Car does not start on ocassions until i fiddle with the key in the ignition little.
When ignition is on switch the imobiliser light is off car will not crank or anything.
After a bit of fiddling and removing the key and put it back in then imobiliser light turns on and car starts normally.
I got a new key and got it programed and same problem. On occasions.
Got a mechanic to check the car battery and its good.
N.b this happens only at times.

There are Hyundai forums that may help; intermittent ignition switch may be the issue.

If the ignition key is on a key ring with other ignition keys, try using the key alone with no other keys nearby. If the key uses an RF transponder and another key's transponder is close to it, the car may be receiving replies from two transponders at once, causing confusion.

[tag:MTA](the key has no other keys or anything on it) and mo other keys kn the var or close to the car.
